# How to fill in the table if $dy/dt=0.5t$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Fill in the missing values in the table below, given that $dy/dt=0.5t$. Assume that  the rate of growth, given by $dy/dt$, is approximately constant over each unit time interval.

[image]

What exactly am I supposed to do here? I don't think it's just solving the equation and finding the appropriate $C$, and then evaluating at $t=1,2,3,4$. And I need to use the condition that $dy/dt$ is approx. constant over each unit time interval somehow.

Comment: Why wouldn’t you just be solving it like it’s an separable ODE?

Comment: @ItIsLastThursday: If I had to guess, it's because the class hasn't gotten anywhere near that far (and, perhaps, won't). Alternatively, it is so that the class can get practice using methods of approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of the differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = 0.5 t$$

is

$$y(t) = a + 0.25 t^2,$$

for a suitable real parameter $a$. If you assume that $y(0) = 8$, then:

$$y(0) = a + 0.25 \cdot 0^2 = 8 \Rightarrow a = 8 \Rightarrow y(t) = 8 + 0.25 t^2.$$

---

Anyway, if you want to approximate the solution by assuming that the increase is constant in a given time interval, consider that you can use the Euler method:

$$y(t)  = y(t-\tau) + \tau\frac{dy}{dt},$$

where $\tau = 1$ ($\tau$ is the intersample distance).

Therefore:

$$y(t) = y(t-1) + 0.5 t,$$

and hence the **approximate solution** is:

$$
\begin{array}{cllll}
y(0) & & & = & 8\\
y(1) & = & y(0) + 0.5 \cdot 1 = 8 + 0.5 & = & 8.5\\
y(2) & = & y(1) + 0.5 \cdot 2 = 8.5 + 1 & = & 9.5\\
y(3) & = & y(2) + 0.5 \cdot 3 = 9.5 + 1.5 & = & 11\\
\ldots
\end{array}
$$
and so on.

Notice that the **real solution** $y(t) = 8 + 0.25 t^2$ gives instead the following values:

$$
\begin{array}{cllll}
y(0) & = & 8 + 0.25 \cdot 0^2 & = & 8\\
y(1) & = & 8 + 0.25 \cdot 1^2 & = & 8.25\\
y(2) & = & 8 + 0.25 \cdot 2^2 & = &9\\
y(3) & = & 8 + 0.25 \cdot 3^2 &= & 10.25\\
\ldots
\end{array}
$$
and so on.

Comment: If he doesn't know how to solve an ODE, I don't think he would understand the meaning of the notation: $\dot{y}$

Comment: @QFi Thanks, I've fixed the notation.

Comment: What if $dy/dt$ were an expression of $y$ instead of $t$, say $f(y)$? Then $y(1)$ would be $y(0)+f(y)$, which is not a number.

Comment: @user638943 why is is not a number?

Comment: If $dy/dt=f(y)$ and $y(t)=y(t-1)+dy/dt$, then $y(1)=y(0)+f(y)$. Here $f(y)$ is still a function.

Comment: @user638943 In that case you can use $f(y(t-1))$. Now, if you know $y(t-1)$, then you now the value of $f(y(t-1))$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You are given:$$y'(t)=0.5t$$
By integrating, you have:
$$y(t)=\dfrac{0.5}{2}t^2+K$$
where K is a constant that is is defined from:
$$y(0)=K=8$$
Thus,

$$y(t)=0.25t^2+8$$